# VB - increasing the score or decreasing the lives value by 1, when using the results from the previous form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

This was done in a Windows Forms Application

how do i make this code increase the score or decrease the lives by 1, when it is using the score from the previous form.

the first one has the score and lives as a set value which it can take away or add onto, however the second form is using the label from the first one which has the results from the first set of code, and i need it to take away the lives by 1 or increase the score by 1 but im not sure what code to use on the second form to do this. i think that i need to increase only the number but im not sure how.

Here is the code from the first form:

```
    Dim score As Integer = 0
    Dim lives As Integer = 3

    If RadioButton3.Checked Then
        score = score + 1
        Label3.Text = "Score: " & score
        Me.Hide()
        Question2.Show()
    ElseIf RadioButton1.Checked Then
        lives = lives - 1
        Label2.Text = "Lives: " & lives
        Me.Hide()
        Question2.Show()
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked Then
        lives = lives - 1
        Label2.Text = "Lives:" & lives
        Me.Hide()
        Question2.Show()
    ElseIf RadioButton4.Checked Then
        lives = lives - 1
        Label2.Text = "Lives:" & lives
        Me.Hide()
        Question2.Show()
    End If

    Question2.Label3.Text = Label3.Text
    Question2.Label2.Text = Label2.Text
```

Second which i am having problems with:

```
    Dim score As Integer
    Dim lives As Integer

    If RadioButton2.Checked Then
        score = score + 1
        Label3.Text = "Score: " & score
        Me.Hide()
        Question3.Show()
    ElseIf RadioButton1.Checked Then
        lives = lives - 1
        Label2.Text = "Lives: " & lives
        Me.Hide()
        Question3.Show()
    ElseIf RadioButton3.Checked Then
        lives = lives - 1
        Label2.Text = "Lives:" & lives
        Me.Hide()
        Question3.Show()
    ElseIf RadioButton4.Checked Then
        lives = lives - 1
        Label2.Text = "Lives:" & lives
        Me.Hide()
        Question3.Show()
    End If

    Question3.Label3.Text = Label3.Text
    Question3.Label2.Text = Label2.Text
```

Comment: The code in each example is almost identical, with the exception of references to `Question2` and `Question3`, which I assume are forms. When you find yourself writing duplicate code, this is when you should ask yourself "can I write this once, and reuse it?". VB.net is object-oriented, and you should leverage that. If will make your life easier.

Comment: Anyway, to answer your question, I will need to know what `Question2` and `Question3` are.

Comment: Is this VB.Net, VBA, or some other version of BASIC. Please edit your question to remove the tags that don't apply.

Comment: Judging from `Dim score As Integer = 0` it is VB.net

Comment: yes this is VB.net

Comment: Question 2 is form 2 and question 3 is the third form which i will be able to fix after i solve this problem between question 1 (form1) and question 2 (form 2)

Comment: This is a questionnaire that i have created and if you answer a question correct then your score will increase by 1, and if you answer incorrect then your lives will drop by 1. since question 1 (form 1) has the score and values already set (0 and 3) it has something to take away from, however for question 2 (form 2) i used the label from question 1 which had the correct points from the question and were displayed on question 2. However if i answer the question correct the answer will increase a lot to 4 and if i answer it wrong it will go to minus 1.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the problem is that you are storing numeric values in labels, in the .Text properties of the controls, which are of type String. The code

```
Label3.Text = "Score: " & score
```

is troubling because the & operator concatenates two strings, while "Score: " is in fact a string, but score is an Integer. Putting the option `Option Strict On` at the top of your code fill will remind you that this is not the right way of doing things. The right way would be

```
Label3.Text = "Score: " & score.ToString()
```

but this doesn't solve your problem.

So the problem is in that the public variable which is accessible from form to form is the .Text property in your label, which holds the string value "Score: 3" (or whatever the score is), so it's difficult to extract the score. You could do a string operation to extract it, since you know you put "Score: " in front of the numeric score, you could replace it with "" and convert to an integer:

```
Dim scoreIn3 As Integer = Integer.Parse(Question2.Label3.Text.Replace("Score: ", ""))
```

This line could be used in the form Question3, to extract the score from the form Question2. You can see that the way to extract the score is convoluted, but this is a product of your design. This may be a small project and doesn't warrant much design consideration, but for any serious project, you should consider using classes and objects to store data, and forms only for display and input. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to suggest that you can use this:

```
Public Shared score As Integer
Public Shared lives As Integer
```

it needs to be placed outside of a sub but inside the form class 
that way they  can be called and changed by all forms in the
application by the following method of whatever form its declared on:

```
Form_Name.score = number
Form_Name.lives = number
```

also when doing it that way you will only need to declare it on one form and
it can be used across them all

a little tip for shortening your code a little bit as well instead of using
something like `lives = lives + 1` or `lives = lives - 1` you can use `lives -= 1` or `lives += 1` for the same effect a slightly shorter way of writing it.
it will also work for other equations like Multiplication and Division by just changing the sign behind the `=` like so: `lives *= 5` and `lives /= 5` just for an example of multiplying or dividing by 5